# How do I serve static pages from outside of my project?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm currently building a web application where people can reserve vacation rentals. One of my requirements is to break this into two separate projects. One for the front end and one for the back end. My questions is what is the best way to serve files in my front end project from my node server in my back end project?

Comment: I don't see how this relates to angularjs.  That may be the front end framework you are using, but including the tag when the question doesn't relate to it only serves to make the question more confusing, imo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security reasons, and maintenance reasons.

The most recommended way is to separate it to two servers. One for frontend static files, the second for the backend.

The static project, you can serve using `serve` npm package. It will open port only for static files.

Then you can create a subdomain for each project. for example:

- `www.myproject.com`
- `api.myproject.com`

Or you can serve the same project from one domain, using NGINX:

- `www.myproject.com`
- `www.myproject.com/api`

If you use NGINX, you don't need a separate server for static files. NGINX can serve the frontend static html files, and every url that starts with `/api` will be forwarded to your backend.

More info:

- https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve

When you have more traffic, you may want to serve your static files, from a cloud storage (For e.g. Amazon S3), or you would like to implement a cache system (For  e.g. CloudFlare). For that reason, it will be easy for start from the beginning by seperating the project for backend and frontend.